# uniq -u returns nothing

Tags: output, uniq

I ve been trying to use uniq -u to print the unique lines of a file with a single column

```
uniq -u samples3
```

but I get nothing! No output! The original file is pretty big (ca. 40mil lines) but still it makes no sense that i get no output...

I have already sorted it, so, what do I do wrong?

example file (only part of the original one):
https://filebin.net/okmotq7t6p2g67o3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does the trick perfectly

```
awk '!a[$1]++' < samples3
```